# Trying to Speed up my Script Compare 2 arrays (not a for loop)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to compare two columns in my sheet 1 column is a list of all email addresses that have ever made a purchase with us which is in excess of 50000 and the other column which is a list of emails that have made a purchase with us in the past month. I'm trying to just count the new email addresses by comparing it from master list.

I've got something to works with a smaller list but it keeps timing out when I index my list of 50000+. Is there anyway to speed my script up?

```
function compareList(){
var s= SpreadsheetApp.openById('My sheet ID');
var ss = s.getSheetByName("Compare");
var oldsubs = ss.getRange(5,1,ss.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
var newsubs = ss.getRange(5,2,ss.getLastRow(),1).getValues();


var array = newsubs.filter(function(e) {return oldsubs.filter(function(f) {return f[0] == e[0]}).length == 0});
Logger.log(array.length)
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Is there reason you particularly want to avoid a for-loop? Sometimes, it is just faster...

Comment: For Loops are great for small amounts of data and I particularly like them because I can see my code working 1 at a time but when I have 50000+ lines it will take too long and google app scripts have a time limit to execute the script and will just cancel the script if it exceeds this so its a no go for this project in particular

Comment: 50000 iterations is really not very much per se; it depends what you're doing. I used a for-loop and compared with the given answer for 100k rows, and it took about 70% of the time. Of course, there are many factors with the timing and the given answer is definitely better than a for-loop for readability, but I still maintain that "for-loops can be faster" and shouldn't be neglected out of hand just because of the large number of iterations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
function newnotinold() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var ss = s.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var o = ss.getRange(2, 1, ss.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().flat();
  var n = ss.getRange(2, 2, ss.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().flat();
  let newnotinold = n.filter(x => !~o.indexOf(x));
  Logger.log(newnotinold);
}
```

Comment: Hi @cooper Thanks for this! just tried this but I get a syntax error. Is 'x' meant to be defined as a variable?

Comment: What's the syntax error?  I tested with my own data and it worked for me.  x is replace the   element that filter iterates through like any other array method.  Perhaps you need to change the sheet names I tend to use what I already have as I tend to use the same spreadsheet for all questions because I have several tools in them which make answering questions a little easier.

Comment: You are right it works! I was running on rhino and not V8. Should have checked that first. Is there anyway I can just count the results rather than return the values? I've tried adding ".length" to the end but it just returns "null" which is confusing because it has been returned into an array am I missing something?

Comment: This provides me with the length `Logger.log(newnotinold.length);` so I don't know what you did.

Comment: Of course, it would work now! Thanks for your help on this. Always so helpful.

Comment: Did it speed things up?

Comment: Without a doubt! it processes 70000 lines in 3 seconds. Far quicker than my original script.

Comment: The highlight for me in this answer is the trick with the bitwise NOT and indexOf() being falsy when x is not found. Hadn't seen it before and had to look it up, and learnt a whole new pile of stuff at the same time.

Comment: I learned it from another question just a few weeks ago.  I think flattening it helps a lot. BTW flat() is not in the code completion but it does work. Mario uses it all of the time